# react native, How to use array filter when we have two parameter first name and last name

Tags: react-native, filter

React native, I have one array with two parameters one in the first name and second in the last name. I have to use a filter with two parameters. Here is my code

```
onSearchInputChanged = (event) => {
        const pattern = new RegExp(event.nativeEvent.text, 'i');
        const contacts = this.state.ary_data.filter(function (datum) {
            return (datum.user_firstname.indexOf(event.nativeEvent.text) !== -1);
        });
        this.setState({
            refreshing: true,
            filtered: contacts
        });//... end state
        setTimeout(this.timerfunction, 100)

    };
```

The array look like this

```
[{
user_firstname: "Ankit"
user_id_sender: "1"
user_image: "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/girl.png"
user_lastname: "C"
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:

```
    onSearchInputChanged = (event) => {
        // const pattern = new RegExp(event.nativeEvent.text, 'i');
        let contacts = this.state.ary_data.filter(function (datum) {
            return datum.user_firstname.match(event.nativeEvent.text) || datum.user_lastname.match(event.nativeEvent.text)
        });
        this.setState({
            refreshing: true,
            filtered: contacts
        });//... end state
        setTimeout(this.timerfunction, 100)

    };
```

Comment: You can also upvote this answer so other can get help from the answer.